# Would like a sentence as a tattoo - having trouble translating English to Italian

Tags: translation

I've got a sentence that I would like to translate into Italian. I have a very, very limited knowledge of the Italian language so I'm a little stumped, ha, ha.

The sentence I would like translated is: "I struggle but I'll survive". It's to be used as a standalone sentence in a tattoo.

Google Translate translates this to "Faccio fatica ma io sopravviverò". Is this accurate? As I know GT can't really be trusted.

Thank you,
Andy

Comment: The translation is roughly correct. Some more context would be useful for a more idiomatic translation. Moreover, aren't requests for translation off-topic for this site?

Comment: See http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-translation-requests-on-topic

Comment: @DenisNardin No because I've already provided the research I've already found. My question is more like the second part of that link - the on topic rather than the first off topic section. This is to be a tattoo so it's just this sentence

Comment: At the very least, I'd remove the subject *io*: «*Faccio fatica ma sopravviverò*». Then, *faccio fatica* means indeed “I struggle”, but conveys more the idea that you are tiring, panting, sweating, more than, say, a fight against destiny or whomever. Is that the right image? Can you paraphrase your sentence? Is it something on the lines of «It won't be easy but I'll survive»?

Comment: @DaG It's indeed meant to mean something like fighting against destiny like a "motto" in life not to be literal translation into tiring, it's meant more as a "I'm determined in life and will come out on top despite my struggles" - does that make sense?

Comment: "Lotto ma sopravviverò".

Comment: I'd say something more like *Sarà dura, ma ce la farò* (It will be hard but I'll make it)

Comment: @DenisNardin that sounds like the best version so far I think

Comment: @DenisNardin: Could you write it as an answer?

Comment: *Barcollo ma non mollo* ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is worth an answer, but here it is.

While not uncorrect the translation from Google translate has some points that mark it as a little unnatural:

- Using the verbal form *Faccio fatica* has a connotation of physical or mental effort that, while also present in the English *I struggle*, is more pronounced in Italian. I think it would be a good translation in sentences like *I struggle with grammar* or *He even struggles to walk*.
- The subject is often omitted in Italian when it is a pronoun. Again, this is not a mistake, per se, but it disrupts the flow of the sentence, putting more emphasis on the subject
- The verb *sopravviverò* (I'll survive) is not what I'd use. I do not have any good rationale for this, but to me at least it has some undertones of "shrugging" (like someone said *Oh well, I'll live* in English). It is a personal interpretation and I'm sure other Italian speakers will disagree strongly with me on this.

The most idiomatic translation I'm able to make is

> Sarà dura, ma ce la farò

that literally means *It will be hard, but I'll make it*.

Comment: I am an Italian speaker and completely concur with your take on *sopravviverò*. *Farcela* is much better. For a tattoo one *could* even go with *barcollo ma non mollo*, which unfortunately could be interpreted either as too tongue-in-cheek or, due to the regrettable history of the verb *mollare*, as - http://www.ilventennio.it/barcollo-mollo-p-30.html